# Unit testing class specification

Tags: java, unit-testing

I wanted to test the specification of the class in a way that when an annotation is removed from the getter method the tests should fail and warn that specification of class has changed.

```
class SomeBean{

   @XMLElement(name = "name")
   public String getName(){
     return name;
   }
}

class SomeBeanUnitTest{
   @Test
   public void test_getNameMustHaveAnnotation(){
      Method getNameMethod = SomeBean.class.getDeclaredMethod("getName", new Class<?>[]{});
      assertNotNull(getNameMethod.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class));
   }
}
```

Do testing methods for declared annotations is a proper way to check the specification of class? As this will make the tests more brittle, but it will provide proper feedback that the annotation was removed from the getter method. Is it advisable to write such tests?

This condition is even covered in Integration test, but the feedback provided by Integration will not point out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

It depends on how important/*crucial to your application working* that annotation is. This of course may sound very general as one might assume that every piece of code is important for application to function properly.

I'll give you example from my own backyard - we use annotation testing to verify whether *methods* of classes implementing certain interface are marked with `[Transaction]` attribute. Why is this important? Beacuse it's very easy to:

- forget to mark method
- remove attribute accidentally
- become a victim of unfortunate merging accident

What is worse, when the method *isn't* marked with `[Transaction]`, at first glance nothing bad happens. Application runs and functions properly. But as you might have probably guessed, such method doesn't run in transaction - which *once in a while* might cause critical error which is extremly **hard to track**. Cost of writing such test / benefit is very low.

Now, how important is `@XMLElement` for proper workings of your application and how critical errors it may cause was it missing is for you to judge. When in doubt, weight the cost vs benefit. As for me, if I could replace any **non deterministic, hard to track/debug error** with automated test (even costly and brittle one), I'd do that anyday.

Comment: Makes sense. Even I feel that no matter how brittle tests are but it should be able to provide feedback about any change in the public behavior of the class. Annotations are part of public meta data, which are used by libraries and its easy to miss them. So I will go with writing these tests any way.